# Generating DDL script for Hibernate 4 / JPA 2.1 requires JDBC connection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I must be missing something: Trying to generate DDL script from Hibernate 4 / JPA 2.1. Did research and found the following code which fails with "The application must supply JDBC connections" error:

```
public class JpaSchemaExport {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    execute(args[0], args[1]);
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void execute(String persistenceUnitName, String destination) {
    System.out.println("Generating DDL create script to : " + destination);

    final Properties persistenceProperties = new Properties();

    // XXX force persistence properties : remove database target
    persistenceProperties.setProperty(
            org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "");
    persistenceProperties.setProperty(
            AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_DATABASE_ACTION, "none");

    // XXX force persistence properties : define create script target from
    // metadata to destination
    // persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_CREATE_SCHEMAS,
    // "true");
    persistenceProperties.setProperty(
            AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_SCRIPTS_ACTION, "create");
    persistenceProperties.setProperty(
            AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_CREATE_SOURCE, "metadata");
    persistenceProperties
            .setProperty(
                    AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_SCRIPTS_CREATE_TARGET,
                    destination);

    // Persistence.generateSchema(persistenceUnitName, null);
    Persistence.generateSchema(persistenceUnitName, persistenceProperties);
}
```

}

The question is why is it trying to connect to the DB if all that's needed is to generate DDL (and not apply it to DB)? Is there a JPA property that needs to be set to tell it not to connect to the DB?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:61)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:695)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:686)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.determineAppropriateJdbcConnectionContext(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:413)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.access$100(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:69)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$Generation.execute(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:122)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.performGeneration(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:76)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$3.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:822)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.generateSchema(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:807)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.generateSchema(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:172)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.generateSchema(HibernatePersistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.generateSchema(Persistence.java:87)
at com.cvc.adservice.config.JpaSchemaExport.execute(JpaSchemaExport.java:55)
at com.cvc.adservice.config.JpaSchemaExport.main(JpaSchemaExport.java:26)
```

And here's persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="DAI" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> -->
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

A JPA implementation usually needs a Connection to get DatabaseMetaData that provides details of available JDBC types, and other capabilities, so that it can use what is supplied in determining the DDL to generate. Can't answer for why Hibernate needs it, but for others it is like that

Comment: Neil, thank you for your reply. In the code, it specifies hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect. It looks like it tells JPA what DB and what version it deals with which is important when generating DDL. You mentioned about JDBC type. Why would it matter for generating DDL? It seems to be the DDL should be agnostic of JDBC type. So, why connect to DB just for generating DDL?

Comment: JDBC/SQL type matters for DDL because in all column definitions in DDL there is an SQL type specified (as well as info about the max length of such columns etc - take a look at DatabaseMetaData). What info Hibernate stores in its "dialect" i've no idea, but the JPA impls I've tried they only have minimal info internally (to cater for where the JDBC is incorrect/incomplete), and rely on the JDBC driver to say what is supported (otherwise you have to wait until the JPA provider class is updated before those things become available when a new JDBC driver is released).

Comment: The SQL type mappings along with their sizes are provided in the "dialect". The super classes for Oracle10gDialect (most of them are in Oracle8iDialect) provide those mappings. Example: registerColumnType( Types.CHAR, "char(1)" );